# Incorrect results in math operations (MS Query Excel)

Tags: microsoft-excel, sql, query

I have this table (vol_week) with four columns. Example:

```
date_ent  | ped_kg | prd_kg | ref_kg
12/9/2017 | 345,22 | 321,23 | 12,56
```

I'm trying to calculate (ped_kg - prd_kg + ref_kg), but the query returns erratic values. Sometimes correct, sometimes close values.

```
SELECT date_ent, iif((Sum(ped_kg)-Sum(prd_kg)+Sum(ref_kg))<0,0,(Sum(ped_kg)-Sum(prd_kg)+Sum(ref_kg))) AS sld_kg
FROM vol_week
WHERE date_ent Is Not Null
GROUP BY date_ent
ORDER BY date_ent
```

I'm using MS Query in MSExcel.

**EDIT: Problem solved :)**
The query was calculating using negative values. This way the query consider zeros from `<0,0` condition:

```
SELECT date_ent, Sum(iif(((ped_kg-prd_kg)+ref_kg)<0,0,(ped_kg-prd_kg)+ref_kg)) AS sld_kg
FROM vol_week
WHERE date_ent Is Not Null
GROUP BY date_ent
ORDER BY date_ent
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is ok. Perhaps a problem with the data (format).
Meybe incorrectly interpret the data returned by mquery
Just a large single value for `prd_kg so` that the aggregate function returns 0 for the entire population (see example below) [image: see example].

Try to re-prepare mquery by pasting the sql query into the dedicated field.

Comment: Thank you. You helped me see the problem. It was math.
What I need is to calculate each row `(ped_kg - prd_kg + ref_kg)`, returning zero for the negatives and then sum the results of the lines, grouping by date.
I need help building the query. Thanks again!

Comment: @Diogenes please vote if I help you. Thanks.